# grails validation using matches constraints - regex

Tags: regex, grails, grails-constraints

Im really having a hard time in matches constraints in grails, im pretty new in it. what i wanted my field to only accept is an input with a format of a phone number, like 02-3546352 where (Area Code)-(Telephone Number). where other characters except numbers and dash are not accepted.Is it possible to filter my input like what i wanted to happen just using regex?
please help. thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that that is the only pattern you want to match...

Something like this: `^\d{2}-\d{7}$` should match any string which starts (`^`) with any two digits (`\d{2}`) follow by a dash (`-`) and which is then followed by 7 digits (`\d{7}`) which is finally followed by the end of the string (`$`).

Take a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) tutorial for more information.

Comment: thanks! i learned something from you. thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's `\d+\-\d+`. If you know exact count of mnumbers in area code and telephone, say 2 for area, and 7 for actual numbler, then it will be `\d{2}\-\d{7}`

Or full example:

```
static constraints = {
   phone(matches: '\\d{2}\\-\\d{7}')
}
```